# Max number of 'b' values That Must Be Calculated for a Single Base in the Miller-Rabin Primality Test

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, computational-mathematics, primality-test

The Miller-Rabin test assumes that any odd number can be written in the form: `p-1 = 2^k * m`. and that: `m` must be `odd` or `p` is not prime.

```
a = chosen base
```

Then you calculate `B0 = a^m * mod(p)`

if `B0 = 1 or -1 (p-1)` then it is probably prime, however if not then you calculate B1, B2... until you get `1 or -1 (p-1)`

This is done by:

```
Bn = (Bn-1)^2*mod(p)
```

So, my question is: Is there a way to calculate the maximum number of `B iterations` you must calculate in order to get `1 or -1 (p-1)` for a given value of `p`, and if so, what is it?